# Asynchronous Processing=True;

Tags: c#, sql, database-connection, connection-string

How `Asynchronous Processing=True;` affects on SQLConnectionString. Can this one be reason of error **The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.**?

Comment: Can you post a bit more on where / how you use the sql and that command?

Comment: as the error told us: do you use the database before and don't close it? this error is for the connection is open.

Comment: I'm interesting in, if two connection can cross each other and get this error